# Set host -> IP mapping from INSIDE DOCKER CONTAINER

Tags: docker, networking, dns, containers, hosts

I want to set a hosts-file like entry for a specific domain name FROM MY APPLICATION INSIDE a docker container. As in, I want the app in the container to resolve `x.com:192.168.1.3`, automatically, without any outside input or configuration. I realize this is unconventional compared to canonical docker use-cases, so don't @ me about it :)

I want my code to, on a certain branch, use a different hostname:ip mapping for a specific domain. And I want it to do it automatically and without intervention from the host machine, docker daemon, or end-user executing the container. Ideally this mapping would occur at the container infrastructure level, rather than some kind of modification to the application code which would perform this mapping itself.

How should I be doing this?

**Why is this hard?**

- The `/etc/hosts` file in a docker container is read-only and is not able to be modified from inside the container. This is by design and it's managed by the docker daemon.
- DNS for a docker container is linked to the DNS of the underlying host in a number of ways and it's not smart to mess with it too too much.

**Requirements**:

- Inside the container, domain `x.com` resolves to non-standard, pre-configured IP address.
- The container is a standard Docker container running on a host of indeterminate configuration.

**Constraints:**

- I can't pass the configuration as a runtime flag (e.g. `--add-host`).
- I can't expose the mapping externally (e.g. set a DNS entry on the host machine).
- I can't modifying the underlying host, or count on it to be configured a certain way.

**open questions:**
is it possible to set DNS entries from inside the container and override host DNS for the container only? if so, what's a good light-weight low-management tool for this (e.g. `DNSmasq`, `coredns`)?

is there some magic by which I can impersonate the `/etc/hosts` file or add a pre-processed file before it in the resolution chain?

Comment: How about editing `/etc/resolv.conf` to use a DNS server on the localhost, and have that DNS proxy the original DNS, except for that one mapping?

Comment: hm well, so I won't have control over the underlying host in any way. Ideally I'd like this to be totally transparent to the consumer.

Comment: You don't need it, you need to run a DNS server inside the container, and edit `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the container.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for when/in what way to edit `resolv.conf`, given it is copied from the host at container runtime and can be arbitrarily managed by docker AFIK?

I've run into problems editing the hosts file with `sed -i`, for example, and would like to avoid that. I guess I could run a routine in my program which checks the resolveconf on a regular basis (say, crond) and modifies it; or modify it before my network calls are made.

Comment: This seems like such a reasonable feature to want. Have you managed to find a solution?